# how to reset module imported between tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules

let's say I have a module that needs to be initialized once in the start of the app (to pass on configuration). module will look something like this :

**MyModule.js**

```
let isInitiazlied;

const myModule = {

    init: function() {
        isInitiazlied = true;
    },
    do: function() {
        if (!isInitiazlied)
            throw "error"
        //DO THINGS
    }
}

export default myModule;
```

I want to unittest it, using jest. test file looks something like this :

**MyModule.test.js**

```
import myModule from './MyModule'

describe('MyModule', () => {
    describe('init', () => {
        it('not throws exception when called', () => {
            expect(() => myModule.init()).not.toThrow();
        });
    })
    describe('do', () => {
        it('throw when not init', () => {
            expect(() => myModule.do()).toThrow();
        });
    })
})
```

when I run the test, the 2nd test fail, as the module already initialized so the exception is not thrown.
I tried using jest.resetModules() in beforeEach, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to solve it (different module pattern/test case) ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have to re-import or re-require your module.
Check the doc or this issue for more information:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3236

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules

```
describe('MyModule', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules()
    });

    describe('init', () => {
        const myModule = require('./MyModule');

        it('not throws exception when called', () => {
            expect(() => myModule.init()).not.toThrow();
        });
    })
    describe('do', () => {
        const myModule = require('./MyModule');

        it('throw when not init', () => {
            expect(() => myModule.do()).toThrow();
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: works ! thanks. the only thing missing was adding **.default** to the require statement, as MyModule exported as default

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I created a little helper function to help take care of resetting env vars between/after tests and providing a friendly API for doing this: https://gist.github.com/DesignByOnyx/8384f190ba363d5003f73578c7e36285

Comment: this should not be the correct accepted answer, require oddly did not work, even if it is in the jest docs

Comment: this example isn't really **doing** anything with the module that's different between the two tests

Answer (score 19):

@ltamajs solution is great for `require` but in the case you are using `import` then you will receive the next error.

```
SyntaxError: /path/to/test/file.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

To solve this issue, you can use the [`babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) plugin and then reset the modules. Overall, it looks like this:

```
describe('MyTests', () => {
  let MyModule;

  beforeEach(() => {
    return import('../module/path').then(module => {
      MyModule = module;
      jest.resetModules();
    });
  });

  test('should test my module', () => {
    expect(MyModule.aMethod).not.toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3236#issuecomment-698271251

Comment: This works great for me even w/o the babel plugin, thanks!

Comment: You can even keep `MyModule` typed if you write it as `let MyModule: typeof import('../module/path')`

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly work, your beforeEach is returning a promise which you are not awaiting

Comment: @MichaelSherrisCaley "`beforeEach` ... can handle asynchronous code [by] returning a promise" - see https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#repeating-setup-for-many-tests

Comment: @Lucio shouldn't the anonymous function be async, i.e. `beforeEach(async () => { ... })` for it to be awaited?

Similar to how Jest docs recommends using the `async` keyword for async tests: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait

Comment: Nevermind. I tested this by putting a long sleep function and beforeEach awaits completing execution regardless of the await keyword.

Comment: it's really unclear why `jest.resetModules();` is inside the import callback -- it seems like you'd want to reset and then import so you get a "fresh" copy of the module assigned to `MyModule`

Comment: Also in TS I get "You need to run with a version of node that supports ES Modules in the VM API." -- just in case someone using TS finds this (Node 18, module set to `es2022`)

Answer (score 0):

In my case only re-requiring didn't work. I got through jest documentation and found [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules).
This suggest use of **jest.resetModules()**.
This basically just resets the cache and on re-requiring module it makes sure it gets loaded from scratch.
So when ever you want are re-requiring use this to make sure the it is getting loaded from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the process.env does not work very well with Jest across all Node platforms. After trying various options I realized there is a very simple fix to solve this issue  using regular jest mock by adding a wrapper function for retrieving process.env. This will avoid having unexpected behaviors cross platforms.

Those who are new to Jest here is a complete solution.
Add a JS file nodeEnvironment.js with the function as follows

```js
const getNodeEnvironment = () => {
  return process.env;
};

export default getNodeEnvironment;
```

Then import the getNodeEnvironment function as normally you would do.

```js
import getNodeEnvironment from './nodeEnvironment';

const myMainFunction= () => {
     const env = getNodeEnvironment();
     const myVarVal = env.myVar    
 }
```

and then use the jest mock.
Please note you will need to set esModule flag to true if you want your function to be default export and then add return default: mockvalue as follows.

```js
jest.mock('./nodeEnvironment', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => {
    //here set all variables you need for your tests
    const env = { myVar: "123" }; 
    return env;
  },
}));
```