# Reseting node module in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a Node.js app where `index.js` has different exports for Unix-like and Windows platforms.

```
import os from "os";

function throwNotSupportedError() {
  throw new Error("Platform not supported.");
}

console.log(os.platform());

switch (os.platform()) {
  case "darwin":
  case "linux":
    module.exports = {
      foo: require("./unix/foo"),
      bar: require("./unix/bar")
    };
    break;
  case "win32":
    module.exports = {
      foo: require("./win32/foo"),
      bar: require("./win32/bar")
    };
    break;
  default:
    throwNotSupportedError();
}
```

And I am trying to cover this file with unit tests which looks like this:

```
import os from "os";

jest.mock("os");

describe("Linux platform", () => {
  test("has `foo` and `bar` methods on Linux platform", () => {
    os.platform.mockImplementation(() => "linux");

    const app = require("../src");
    expect(app.foo).toBeTruthy();
    expect(app.bar).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

describe("Windows platform", () => {
  test("has `foo` and `bar` methods on Windows platform", () => {
    os.platform.mockImplementation(() => "win32");

    const app = require("../src");
    expect(app.foo).toBeTruthy();
    expect(app.bar).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The thing is that `os.platform.mockImplementation(() => "win32");` works but     `console.log(os.platform());` still shows `linux` even if I import the app in every test case `const app = require("../src");`.

Where is my mistake and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Khang's answer about [`jest.resetModules()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules) is pointing to the correct direction. I would like to add that when you reset modules, references to any past imports will be "ignored" (a new instance is created after reset). In other words, the `import os from "os";` at the top of your test will no longer be used after the module reset.

**Solution**

In addition to [`jest.resetModules()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules) you need to re-import (or in this case re-require) the `os` module inside the test you are about to execute. By doing so, `os.platform.mockImplementation(() => "win32");` will be applied to the latest instance of the module's mock. Both your tests need to be structured this way;

```
test("has `foo` and `bar` methods on Windows platform", () => {
  const os = require('os');
  os.platform.mockImplementation(() => "win32");

  const app = require("./os-test");
  expect(app.foo).toBeTruthy();
  expect(app.bar).toBeTruthy();
});
```

You might want to use `beforeEach` instead of `afterEach`, to ensure that the `os` module is clean before the test. Jest should isolate each test file, but better safe than sorry? Finally, you would want to have the `beforeEach` to run before all tests, not just inside the "Windows platform" `describe`. To do that you can either move it to the root of the file or wrap the two `describe` in an additional `describe`, e.g.

```
jest.mock("os");

describe('Platform specific module', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  describe("Linux platform", () => {
    test("has `foo` and `bar` methods on Linux platform", () => {
      const os = require('os');
      os.platform.mockImplementation(() => "linux");
      ...
```

I hope this helps! Mocking tends to be tricky, not just in Jest.

**References**

- [`jest.resetModules()` official documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules)
- [how to reset module imported between tests (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48989643/1300306)

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the `os` module in the scope of your test, but your actual code uses the module in its own scope. `jest.mock` only takes the exported methods and replaces them with `jest.fn`, so, in theory, your code needs to export `os`, then your test code should just require your code *once* at the top of the file. Your test code should not import `os` directly.

This is just untested theory, by the way, from reading [a tutorial on Jest mocks](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [`jest.resetModules()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestresetmodules) after each test to clear the module cache:

```
describe("Windows platform", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
    })

    //...
})
```