# Is it possible to re-evaluate an imported ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules

I am trying to write unit tests for a redux application. I have a common `store.js`:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './root-reducer';

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

And the test file:

```js
// necessary imports and mocks

describe('store', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    redux.createStore.mockClear();
    redux.applyMiddleware.mockClear();
    jest.resetModules()
  });

  it('should create the store properly', async () => {
    const stubMiddleware = jest.fn();
    redux.applyMiddleware.mockImplementation(() => stubMiddleware);

    await import('./store');

    expect(redux.createStore).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(redux.createStore).toHaveBeenCalledWith(rootReducer, stubMiddleware);
  });

  it('should apply thunk middleware', async () => {
    redux.applyMiddleware.mockImplementation(() => {});

    await import('./store');

    expect(redux.applyMiddleware).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(redux.applyMiddleware).toHaveBeenCalledWith(thunk);
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the second test case will fail, since the store module is evaluated only once at the first import and I clear all the mocks after each test.

Actually the problem is pretty specific, but the question is broader. We have many tools where we need to add side-effects to our modules, like here, creating a store.
How can these side-effects get tested? My first solution was exporting a `getStore()` method which was kind of an implementation of the singleton DP, but again, in that case, the module was stateful by the singleton instance which might require re-evaluation in certain cases.

I've also tried `jest.resetModules()` and `jest.isolateModules()` but they didn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989643/how-to-reset-module-imported-between-tests is similar but `require` didn't do the trick neither

Comment: In general: just put it inside a function.

Comment: For specific cases, you sometimes have control over the module loader and can use tricks to reload the module, like in Jest tests. But using a function is simpler and works everywhere.

Comment: @Bergi I don't really understand, it is already in a function, the second parameter of the test-case is a function

Comment: I mean you should put the code that you want to re-evaluate in a function, in this case the `createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))` .

Comment: I've mentioned my problem with that approach, it would create more redux store in the application

Comment: Are you referring to the `getStore()` function you mentioned? I was not suggesting a stateful singleton pattern which creates only one store, I meant a factory function that creates a new store every time you call it.

Comment: Yes, it would be an approach especially if I would use react and react-redux then it is easy to pass the store to the provider, but I use redux separately and I import it in multiple files, so it would create more redux stores in my application.

Comment: You still can create a single instance in your *main.js* or *app.js* (or even in *store.js*) and then import that everywhere if you need it, but when you need multiple instances for testing then you should not use the singleton pattern.

Comment: We can think of `export default createStore(...)` as singleton, since the module gets evaluated only once and will always export the same store. I Like this approach and I don't want to add more layers to the instantiation. Also, if I create a factory method, I will need to unit test them, where I will face the same issue. I will have a module scoped variable which won't be testeable without re-evaluating another module.
Of course only if I want to keep the one testCase one assertion method.