# Change process.env variable for single test using JEST

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

i have the following code in a file that i'm trying to test:

*foo.js*

```
let localEnv = (process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT).toLowerCase() === 'prod' ? 'prod' : 'stage';
```

currently, i set this value using `setupFiles` which points to `env.js` and it contains:

```
process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = 'prod';
```

my question is, how do i change `process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT` to `test` (or anything else) in `foo.test.js`? Just need to do this in a single test, so this line will be covered in my test coverage.

I tried doing something like this but it didn't work...

*foo.test.js*

```
test('Nonprod', async () => { 
  process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = 'test';
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on how to reset and re-require the tested module here:
[how to reset module imported between tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989643/how-to-reset-module-imported-between-tests)

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the value as you tried. However you have to take into account that in your original file you only access the variable when you first load this script. In order to make this work you have to do sth like this:

```js
// in your test file foo.test.js
const prev = process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT
process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = 'test'; // from now on the env var is test
const myModule = require('./foo.js'); // foo.js is executed and the var is read as test
process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = prev; // change value back
```

This has some caveats as you cant test multiple scenarios with this (as the module is only loaded in once).

If you want to test more scenarios you have multiple options:

One would be to split the logic and process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT apart, for example

```
function getLocalEnv(env = process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT) {
  return env.toLowerCase() === 'prod' ? 'prod' : 'stage';
}
```

This function is now very easy to test and doesn't depend on env vars for that anymore

Comment: Hmm...not sure i entirely follow. What do you mean by original file in the comment "However you have to take into account that in your original file..."

Comment: seems odd there isn't an elegant way to change an environment variable for just a single test...

Comment: sorry, original file i mean `foo.js`. As this file is required it gets executed once, so your localDev gets computed exactly once and with the value process.env. LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT has at the time

Comment: gotcha. that makes sense now. can you further explain the `multiple` options you mentioned and how i might use it instead?

Comment: ah, found the answer here, thanks for the assist:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989643/how-to-reset-module-imported-between-tests

Answer (score 0):

The most easier way to test it for a specific test case is to set the test into a describe scope and to apply / remove the env value in beforeAll / afterAll or beforeEach / afterEach hooks depending on your needs.

```
describe('Test example', () => {
  describe('prod (default)', () => {
    test('do the thing', () => {
      doTheThing(); // process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT is by default 'prod' because of your setupFiles
    });
  });
  describe('test env', () => {
    const oldEnv = process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT; // or { ...process.env } to copy the whole env

    beforeAll(() => {
      process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = 'test';
    });
    afterAll(() => {
      process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = oldEnv; // do not forget to do this
    });

    test('do the thing', () => {
      doTheThing(); // process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT is 'test' here
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: tried this. and while it does change the environment variable, the imported file that is being tested, does not see this.

`let localEnv = (process.env.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT).toLowerCase() === 'prod' ? 'prod' : 'stage';` is ALWAYS `prod` even when using the above method.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your problem. I wanted to answer to the title ("Change process.env variable for single test using JEST"). This way will only work if you're getting the env dynamically in a function, not at the import.

Be careful by using your solution, it may be hard to maintain in a long term, reimporting each file using process.env every time you're editing the process.env variables. But this is the only way to make it works because of the implementation.